# How do I use a Table to filter values and then find them in a row matching other criteria as well?

Tags: excel

Right now I am using `=COUNTIFS(Range!B1:HFQ1, TRUE, NextRange!B1:HFQ1, TRUE)` which is returning the correct count for both cell values in the same row matching `TRUE`.

What I'm trying to do now is throw in a table with text values and count all matches. I want to say it's something like this `=COUNTIFS(Table10[Models], Range!B1:HFQ1, Range!B1:HFQ1, TRUE, NextRange!B1:HFQ1, TRUE)` But that doesn't work.

I've heard about INDEX and MATCH but they don't seem to be doing exactly what I'm asking of them either. I want it ideally to be all in one `COUNTIFS` formula so it can match exact but I need it to match any, all, and/or a subset of the following 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Blue'.